# Using favicon files -- what is purpose of a zero-length favicon.ico in the docroot?

Tags: favicon

When we first started using favicon files, we put a single file named favicon.ico in the docroot. Later, when it because necessary to use multiple files, we put them in a subdirectory and use link tags in the head section, with variations used for different browsers. However at that time we still left the original favicon file in the docroot, presumably for backwards compatibility.

I just started using a third-party code base with our website for analytics purposes (Matomo). I notice that Matomo has in its docroot a favicon file with zero length, and link tags for its actual favicons.

I tried searching on the usage of the favicon in the docroot with zero length but did not find anything. But it occurs to me that this might be a best practice.

Does anyone know why the legacy favicon.ico file in the docroot should be set to zero length?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this was intentional. Seems like a version tracking artifact